# how to allow single quote in anti forgery token

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am passing a string in an MVC action method where anti forgery token is enabled, the string contains   a single quote. I am getting page crash while calling the action method. Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplest solution: eliminate the single quote (the token needs to be randomised, but there are plenty of other characters without encoding issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the single quote by using a back slash as follows:

```
string foo = "How\'s it going?";
```

Comment: it did n't work, it think there needs to be change in anti forgery token

Comment: Are you generating the token yourself?

Comment: No I am not generating token my, ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is being used.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood. The single quote is in a string, not the token? I'm assuming you have tried removing the single quote and it works?